# Updating spatial table in Oracle database with SQL query in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, sql, oracle-dbms

I am trying to use the Python Console within QGIS 3.4 to update a spatial table in an Oracle database. The goal is to update all values in the field `DTM_ELEV` in the Oracle table with values from a layer I created in QGIS. Both tables are identical, except the table I created has an additional field `LIDAR` that I want to use to replace the `DTM_ELEV` values in the Oracle table. The primary key matching the tables is the field `GID`.

Right now, I can complete these updates using the SQL Window in the Database Manager, but I want to automate the process with a Python script. Right now, I have successfully connected to the table I want to edit; I just need help with running the SQL queries within my PyQGIS script.

I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to do this.